# Generate gradient based on css gradient settings in c#

Tags: c#, gradient, system.drawing.color

I want to generate gradient based on css settings.
Example: I have css gradient like this `-moz-linear-gradient(top,#ECFFEF 19%,#788300 83%)` or in `-webkit-gradient` version.

I want to get System.Drawing.Image object which represents the same image as it displays browser. Image size 100x100.

In other words: I need function with parameters - color1(#ECFFEF), color2(#788300), fromPercent(19%), toPercent(83),gradientMode(Vertical or Horizontal) and size(100x100). This functions returns System.Drawing.Image object.

I've wrote somthing:

```
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100))
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(
                new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100),
                color1,
                color2,
                gradientMode))
            {
                brush.SetSigmaBellShape(0);// I am stuck at this place
                graphics.FillRectangle(brush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
            }
```

I am stuck at `brush.SetSigmaBellShape(0);` what is correct settings of gradient's shape? Or maybe I am searching at the wrong place?

EDIT: I've found correct settings.
I've replaced line  `brush.SetSigmaBellShape(0);` with next lines of code:

```
Blend blend = new Blend();
                blend.Factors = new float[] {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
                blend.Positions = new float[]
                                      {
                                          0.0f, (float) fromPercent/100, (float) (fromPercent+ toPercent)/200,
                                          (float) toPercent/100, 1.0f
                                      };

                brush.Blend = blend;
```

Comment: Please post the question in the body of the question, not hidden as a code comment. It is too easily missed.